# How to align svg icon inline with text in boostrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/a7uxLkyt/

I simply want to show text and icon in line. What am I doing wrong? Is the `class="d-inline"` correct?

```
<div>
        <div class="d-inline">inline text</div>
        <div title="Test" class="d-inline" style="fill:grey">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.7071,1.29289075 .... see fiddle"/>
            </svg>
        </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine! The only thing that remains is the size of your SVG. Please define its size or use some CSS codes like:

```
svg {
  width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have given bootstrap classes `align-middle` and `d-inline-block` which will vertically align the text and image, even if the image width increases (currently we have given specific `width:32px;` to the icon).

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/1wm7z5y4/